# Dynamic URL in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I'm working on a React project with Redux and I'm consuming a Rest API, I need to implement a functionality where when I select a project from a list and I need to load the project ID in the URL and direct to another screen where a sidebar with the options is loaded. navigation of this project.
Example: [Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5meRd.png)

I managed to load the project's Id in the URL and retrieve this ID in the project's home screen, the problem is to store the project's Id and set this ID in the next selected URLs, for example:

`path: '/project/:id/companies'`
 `path: '/project/:id/currencies'`
 `path: '/project/:id/settings'`

**List of projects:**

Capture the project id and arrow the url:
`` href={`#/project/${row.id}/main`} ``

**Routes:**

```
path: '/project/:id/main',
exact: true,
name: 'projectMain',
component: RequireAuth(ProjectMain),
```

**Retrieve ID in main**

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
...
const { id } = useParams();
```

The problem is in the sidebar, where I load a list of items with the path, I'm not able to pass the project id in this list.

Complementando a pergunta

In Sidebar I'm using useHistory(), the problem is that the path comes static by 'props' through importing a file into my template, as you can see below:
**Template**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';    
import {
  AppContent,
  AppHeader,
  SidebarApp,
} from '../components/index';
import itemsProject from '../components/itemsSidebar/itemsProject';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  appContent: {
    paddingLeft: 240,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
}));

const ProjectLayout = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.appContent}>
      <AppHeader />
      <Grid container direction="row">
        <SidebarApp items={itemsProject} />
        <AppContent />
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};    
export default ProjectLayout;
```

**Sidebar:**

```
/* eslint-disable react/jsx-no-duplicate-props */
import React from 'react';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import ExpandLessIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandLess';
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';
import {
  alpha,
  Box,
  Card,
  ListSubheader,
  makeStyles,
  Typography,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { useHistory, useLocation, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

import translate from '../providers/i18n/translate';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  sidebar: {
    background: theme.palette.background.dark,
    width: 240,
    height: '100vh',
    border: '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    position: 'absolute',
    paddingTop: 64,
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
  },
  sidebarItem: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  sidebarItemContent: {
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '100%',
  },
  sidebarItemIcon: {
    marginRight: 6,
  },
  sidebarItemText: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  sidebarItemExpandArrow: {
    fontSize: '1.2rem !important',
  },
  sidebarItemExpandArrowExpanded: {
    fontSize: '1.2rem !important',
    color: theme.palette.primary.main,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  active: {
    background: alpha(theme.palette.primary.light, 0.2),
  },
}));

function SidebarItem({ depthStep = 10, depth = 0, expanded, item, ...rest }) {
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = React.useState(true);
  const { label, items, Icon, onClick: onClickProp } = item;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();

  function toggleCollapse() {
    setCollapsed(prevValue => !prevValue);
  }

  function onClick(e) {
    if (Array.isArray(items)) {
      toggleCollapse();
    }
    if (onClickProp) {
      onClickProp(e, item);
      history.push(item.path);
    }
  }

  let expandIcon;

  if (Array.isArray(items) && items.length) {
    expandIcon = !collapsed ? (
      <>
        <ExpandLessIcon className={classes.sidebarItemExpandArrowExpanded} />
      </>
    ) : (
      <ExpandMoreIcon className={classes.sidebarItemExpandArrow} />
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ListItem
        className={classes.sidebarItem}
        onClick={onClick}
        button
        dense
        className={location.pathname === item.path ? classes.active : null}
        {...rest}
      >
        <div
          style={{ paddingLeft: depth * depthStep }}
          className={classes.sidebarItemContent}
        >
          {Icon && (
            <Icon
              className={classes.sidebarItemIcon}
              fontSize="small"
              color="primary"
            />
          )}
          <div className={classes.sidebarItemText}>{label}</div>
        </div>
        {expandIcon}
      </ListItem>
      <Collapse in={!collapsed} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        {Array.isArray(items) ? (
          <List disablePadding dense>
            {items.map((subItem, index) => (
              <React.Fragment key={`${subItem.name}${index}`}>
                {subItem === 'divider' ? (
                  <Divider style={{ margin: '6px 0' }} />
                ) : (
                  <SidebarItem
                    depth={depth + 1}
                    depthStep={depthStep}
                    item={subItem}
                  />
                )}
              </React.Fragment>
            ))}
          </List>
        ) : null}
      </Collapse>
    </>
  );
}

function Sidebar({ items, depthStep, depth, expanded }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { key } = useParams();
  return (
    <Card elevation={0} className={classes.sidebar}>
      <List
        disablePadding
        dense
        subheader={
          <ListSubheader component="div" id="nested-list-subheader">
            {translate('sidebarMenuSettings')}
            <Typography>
              <Box>{key}</Box>
            </Typography>
          </ListSubheader>
        }
      >
        {items.map((sidebarItem, index) => (
          <React.Fragment key={`${sidebarItem.name}${index}`}>
            {sidebarItem === 'divider' ? (
              <Divider style={{ margin: '6px 0' }} />
            ) : (
              <SidebarItem
                depthStep={depthStep}
                depth={depth}
                expanded={expanded}
                item={sidebarItem}
              />
            )}
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
      </List>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

**Sidebar list items**

```
function onClick(e, item) {}

const itemsProject = [
 {
  name: 'companies',
  label: translate('sidebarProjectCompanies'),
  Icon: CompanyIcon,
  path: '/project/:id/companies',
  onClick,
 }
 {
  name: 'currencies',
  label: translate('sidebarProjectCurrencies'),
  Icon: CurrencyIcon,
  path: '/project/:id/currencies',
  onClick,
 }
];

export default itemsProject;
```

How can I pass the ID variable on the Sidebar list items?

I thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ES6 template literals as follows.

```
path: `/project/${id}/companies`
```

Comment: That's right, I just needed to convert `itemsProject` into a function and use `useParams()` in the path variable! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you already defined your path, you just need to use useHistory and navigate to the new link

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';
...


const history = useHistory();

...

// call this whenever you want to navigate

history.push(`/project/${id}/currencies`);
```

Comment: I'm using useHistory, but I don't know how I can pass the variable in my "itemsProject" file, I edited the question in more detail.